# Negative binomial estimate output

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution

I am doing a negative binomial regression:

```
m1 <- glm.nb(Trip ~ Origin + Destination + Distance, data)
```

I then wanted to get the predicted values to compare with the actual values

```
PredictTrip <- predict(m1)
```

My question is, I read on several websites that the predicted values need to be exponentiated because it is in log form. However, if I exponentiate the predicted values, it becomes ridiculously large (i.e. E+20, or even Infinity). If I did not exponentiate it, the values are close and comparable to the actual values. Which one is right? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to exponentiate.

When you execute `predict(m1)`, what is called is the `predict.glm()` function. Here is its help page:

```
Usage:

     ## S3 method for class 'glm'
     predict(object, newdata = NULL,
                 type = c("link", "response", "terms"),
                 se.fit = FALSE, dispersion = NULL, terms = NULL,
                 na.action = na.pass, ...)
```

Note in particular the `type` parameter, which governs what *type* of predictions or fits you will get. By default (`type="link"`), you get a prediction on the level of the link function. What you want is a mean response prediction, so do

```
predict(m1, type="response")
```

You may be interested in [Regression predictions show far less variance than expected](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/390210/1352).